# Insert a variable in blank array that variable contains array key and value

Tags: php, arrays

My variable which retrieve from database is:

```
$MyVariable="1=>'raju',2=>'rana',3=>'keya',4=>'muaz',5=>'',6=>'Asif'";
```

My array will be:

```
$MyArray=array($MyVariable);
```

Now I want to print a value using a key. Like:

```
echo $MyArray[2];
```

My output should be:

```
rana
```

But output is nothing!

Comment: What is the output when you do `print_r($MyVariable)`?

Comment: You have a string and not an array! (.. And you should get an error, since you're trying to access an element which doesn't exists)

Comment: If that is your real code, your array will have one element: The string given above.

Comment: Also note that you should not store information like that, you should normalize your database. If you really must store multiple values in one field (don't...), you should serialize the array or object you want to store or encode it as json.

Comment: Well.. you can use `$MyArray=eval("return array($MyVariable);");` but that just.. blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval()` has security implications, but that's how this string of partial crap is turned into an actual array:

```
eval('$MyArray = array('.$MyVariable.');');
print_r($MyArray);
```

You should really store each value as a related row in another table instead of array data.

Comment: Wasn't the `evil()` trip 2 days ago:)?

Comment: Yes, but I failed the last output buffering question :-(

Comment: I would say you flushed your answer buffer too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$myVariable` is a string consisting of array keys.

If you were to write it as an array, it would work without problems:

```
$myvariable = array(
1 => 'raju',
2 => 'rana',
3 => 'keya'
// More entries
);
```

If this is the output of a function, you may want to make that function output JSON instead, as that is parseable to an array with just one [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) call.

If  you still want to parse this, you'll have to do some more advanced string parsing:

```
$data = array();
$bits = preg_match_callback("/(\d+)=>'(.*?)'(\,)?/", function($matches) use ($data){
    $data[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}, $MyVariable);
```